# Create JSON format in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I have two send data to server in JSON format, below is the format which server needs

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" "middelName":"M" "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" "middelName":"J" "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" "middelName":"K" "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Now I have three NSMutableArrays , 1st array contains firstName, second array contains middleName and third array contains lastName,

If it was just a single record I could have created it this way

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"employees": @{@"firstName":"John" "middelName":"M" "lastName":"Doe"}};

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating JSON object: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Now I am getting confused on how to create an array of records

Comment: The firstName, middleName and lastName are not arrays. They are key-values in the dictionary. The arrays are inside the dictionary "employees" within the curly braces{} with comma seperated(,). Therefore your arrays will be:
Array 1 - { "firstName":"John" "middelName":"M" "lastName":"Doe" }
Array 2 - { "firstName":"Anna" "middelName":"J" "lastName":"Smith" }
Array 3 - { "firstName":"Peter" "middelName":"K" "lastName":"Jones" }
*FYI*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/* assuming the arrays have equal length, no error checking */
NSMutableArray * employees = [NSMutableArray new];
NSUInteger idx = 0;
for(NSString * firstName in firstNames) {
    [employees addObject:@{
        @"firstName":firstName,
        @"middleName":[middleNames objectAtIndex:idx],
        @"lastName":[lastNames objectAtIndex:idx]
    }];
    idx++;
}
id sendThis = @{@"employees": employees};
/* do your JSON stuff with sendThis */
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I have small doubt, I have one more array of delete employee list, and I want to attach this also , so how can I do it, and deletedEmployee array length is not same.

Comment: Also I am not getting square brackets at the end

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with "not getting square brackets". I wrote the code directly here, so it may not compile. 
I suggest consulting a book/online tutorial about objective-c and see the different ways you can loop over an array, how to work with dictionaries, etc.
And finally, if the answer worked for you, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

[]---> array , {}--> dictionary

the coding can be like this (just an example though)

```
NSArray *local_array = @[@{@"f":@"ew",@"d":@"new"}];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"employees": local_array};
```

Comment: Hey I tried with your code, but when I NSlog to see the format, I only see flower brackets and no square brackets